# Call a javascript method in a class from a html button

Tags: javascript, oop, methods, onclick

Okay so i have been looking on how to call a method from javascript in an onclick event in for example let's say a button, but i can't find any answers.

This is what I have:

Javascript

```
class SomeClassName() {
   methodName() {
     alert("test");
   }
}
```

html

```
<button type="button" onclick="methodName()">Click me</button>
```

Obviously I didn't expect this to work since you need to make an instance like:

```
Object = new SomeClassName();
Object.methodName();
```

But I can't figure out how to do this on an onclick event.

Comment: where would i need to declare the object? i did this at the top in my script tag but it give an error "Object.methodName is not a function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't define your 'class' with parens

`class SomeClassName()`

additionally, if you want to call a method without instantiating it, you must make that method 'static'

```js
class SomeClassName {
   static methodName() {
     alert("test");
   }
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="SomeClassName.methodName()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out i needed to declare this "Object = new SomeClassName();" after the class and then it worked